# get local transform between 2 matrices

Tags: math, language-agnostic, coordinate-transformation

I want to know the local transformation between 2 matrices.

So for example I have this:

```
Mat3 m = m3_identity();
m = mult(m, imgui.math.rotation(radians(22)));
m = mult(m, imgui.math.translation(100, 0));

Mat3 m2 = mult(m, imgui.math.rotation(radians(45)));
m2 = mult(m2, imgui.math.translation(100, 0));

Mat3 m3 = mult(m2, imgui.math.translation(100, 0));

// trash from here on

float tx = m3.m[0][2];
float ty = m3.m[1][2];

float parent_tx = m2.m[0][2];
float parent_ty = m2.m[1][2];

tx -= parent_tx;
ty -= parent_ty;

println(tx, ty); // expected 100, 0, got 39.07, 92.05
```

Which would give:

[image]

My goal is to have nested elements, which I got working but I would like to show their values.

To give an example, in blender we can have nested elements (children).

[image]

[image]

Now if we have the last cube and look at the transform properties:

[image]

They are seen from the perspective of the parent like so:

[image]

So in my case I want to know the transform of m3 seen from m2.

So that should be x 100 and y 0 in this case.

How can I do this?

In case it helps, my matrix is nothing more then:

```
static public class Mat3 {
    public float[][] m = new float[3][3];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the local translation of an object, it does not suffice to subtract the global position of the object and its parent. In your case, you obtain a vector of norm 100, as expected, but it is also oriented. To fix it, the orientation of the parent needs to be considered. Specifically, you have

```
m3 = R1*T1 * R2*T2 * T3 = m2 * T3
```

where `Ri` and `Ti` are the rotation and translation matrices forming `m` and `m2`. To obtain `T3`, calculate:

```
T3 = inverse(m2) * m3
```

*Note*: If the third transformation also included a rotation (`m3=m2*R3*T3`), you would need to compute `T3=inverse(m2*R3)*m3`.

Comment: What if it is unknown if the third transformation included a rotation? Then it can't hurt? Or what if scaling was involved?

Comment: If the third transformation includes an unknown rotation, you can extract the rotation using the 2x2 submatrix. First compute `m23=inverse(m2)*m3`, then `R3=extract_submatrix22(m23)`, and then `T3=inverse(R3)*m23`. The same applies if the transformations include a scale of the form `Si*Ri*Ti`.

Comment: Yes, as for now it seems it does :)